# Hyperlinks or how to make url in java servlet

Tags: servlets, hyperlink

I am trying to grab data from an API and use it on my website. I grabbed some url for a news articles but I don't know how to make the url as a hyperlink in servlets. So that when visitors click the news link, it will go to either the publishers(API owner) homepage or the exact news link page.

Below is a sample code and the links to be converted to hyperlink:

```
String urll = json.getString("url");
out.println("<br> URL Link: " + urll + "<br>");
```

This is on my webpage is not a link: 
http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/02/23/donald-trump-revokes-barack-obama-guidelines-transgender-bathrooms/

What i need is how to make the link an hyperlink in servlets.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the string a hyperlink at the client side, using javascript.

Have an API in java servlet that returns your `json` variable. Call this API from javascript:

```
$.get('/myApi', function(jsonData){
    var url = jsonData.url;
    $(body).append("<a href='" + url + "'>Click me</a>");
})
```

I'm using a jquery helper function to make the API call.

Comment: I will try it out. Thanks pls!